# How to handle right click to show context menu and edit row in angular using mat table?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, contextmenu, right-click, mat-table

I want to edit Table row in angular material table at the same time I need an contextmenu in the same row without interrupting the edit actions

Comment: are you referring to angular 1 or angular 2+? they have totally different approaches

Comment: angular 2+ @MarkoCen